# Java TableItem, TableEditor, texts and buttons - all dynamically created

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to create a table (that will finally exist in a new eclipse view). This table has a few text columns, and a column that has a different behavior based on the other columns. It can either be a field to enter text, or to popup a dialog for users to select data from (and it has to be a popup or a dynamically created combo). Anyway, I know which of the two I need for each row in the column.

My table is built using `TableViewer` and a few `TableViewerColumn`'s in it. I later fill them with String data in `TableItem`'s up to 4 columns. The fifth is the one I have this special behavior.

I tried experimenting with `TableEditor`, but failed:

- When I used one for each `TableItem` it somehow got misaligned with the table rows and columns
- When I use one for the entire table, I fail to set a Text entry on specific rows

What I need help with is figuring out exactly how to achieve this:

- A Table that has 4 String columns, where the data is constant (cannot be changed by the user)
- A fifth column where the cell contents is either a Text for the user to enter, or a (preferably transparent) Button that has a popup as action, or a Combo that I dynamically fill with data upon table creation

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got this figured out. The example here helped a lot:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/TableCellEditorComboTextandButton.htm

Oren